# Regex ignore optional HTML tags inside captured group

Tags: regex, vb.net

I just wanted to start off by saying i am a VB.Net user and i know all the concerns regarding HTML and Regular Expressions. This is simply for my own learning so please don't suggest alternative ways.

Now for the HTML

```
<td class="alt1 username"><a href="member.php?123-Stack" class="username">Stack</a>
<td class="alt1 username"><a href="member.php?456-Overflow" class="username"><font color="#FF0000"><strong>Overflow</strong></font></a>
```

Now you can see the optional font and string tags. My current pattern will capture the first example fine but also the optional tags. I know why my pattern fails just unsure how to include optional tags. Maybe it's not possible?

```
(?<=<a href=""member\.php\?\d+\-.+?"" class=""username"">).+?(?=</a>)
```

Thanks as always

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in case-insensitive mode:

```
[^<>]+(?=(?:\s*</(?!a>)[^>]*>)*\s*</a>)
```

See the matches in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/10).

To get all the matches in VB.NET:

```
Dim ResultList As StringCollection = New StringCollection()
Try
    Dim RegexObj As New Regex("[^<>]+(?=(?:</(?!a>)[^>]*>)*</a>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim MatchResult As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
    While MatchResult.Success
        ResultList.Add(MatchResult.Value)
        MatchResult = MatchResult.NextMatch()
    End While
Catch ex As ArgumentException
    'Syntax error in the regular expression
End Try
```

**Explanation**

- `[^<>]+` matches chars that are neither `<` nor `>` (this is your match)
- the lookahead `(?=(?:</(?!a>)[^>]*>)*</a>)` asserts that what follows is...
- `(?:</(?!a>)[^>]*>)*` zero or more of tags that are not `</a>`, i.e. `</` not followed by `a>`, then non-`>` chars, then `>`
- then the closing `</a>`

**Extended Spec**

If you want the regex to only match when the class `username` is present, use this instead:

```
(?<=<td class="[^"]*username"><a(?:(?!</a).)+)[^<>]+(?=(?:\s*</(?!a>)[^>]*>)*\s*</a>)
```

Comment: FYI: added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: The solution works amazing with just the Two examples. How ever with the full page captures quite a lot f wrong. I'l see if i can edit to be me more lazy with the html.

Comment: If you add an example, I can see what's going wrong and fix it. Thanks! :)

Comment: When I try this text, my regex seems to match where it should—but it's super long so I didn't spend 30 minutes on it. Why don't you tell me one specific problem? For instance, when you try the demo I gave you, is there one line you can add to make it fail?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Here is the first wrong match.

    <dd><a href="memberlist.php?ltr=%23&amp;pp=30&amp;sort=reputation&amp;order=desc">#</a></dd>

As you can see it's not a user name like

    <td class="alt1 username"><a href="member.php?35765-Sam-Clarke" class="username">Sam Clarke</a>

Thank you for all your hard work. Credit to this site.

Comment: Are you saying you only want to match the text if the class is `username`? If so, do you realize the this is not in your question? Sorry but I am not a psychic. :)

Comment: I never said you was. I appreciate your help i did not mention it because it was in my original pattern.

    class=""username"">

sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please see the "Extended Specs" section at the bottom. Let me know if that's what you need. :)